# Past Simple with "this week"

Tags: simple-past

Is there a mistake in the sentence "He **didn't do** his homework this **week**"?

I mean is it possible to use Past Simple

Answer (score 1):

The answer may be different in British English, but in American English, this is perfectly acceptable.  The sentences would have different connotations depending on whether you use the simple past or the present perfect.

"He hasn't done his homework this week."  Connotation: There is still an opportunity to do homework this week. Either the homework isn't due yet and he can still do it, or more homework may be assigned this week.

"He didn't do his homework this week." Connotation: The opportunity to do homework has passed. The deadline for all of the week's homework has passed.

Comment: Precisely the same in 'BrE' (whatever that is). And ELL if not a multi-duplicate.